# How do I add several books to the bookstore in the admin form

Tags: python, django

In django, imagine i have a model bookstore and a model book which has a foreign key to bookStore model . On the django admin,I added like 10 books, and on the bookstore I want to assign multiple books to this one bookstore. How do I do this ? Because even with foreignKey, while editing the bookstore, i can only choose one book...

```
class BookStore(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    store = models.ForeignKey(BookStore, null=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your relationship is the wrong way around. If your bookstore has a fk to a book, you are saying that "each bookstore can only store one single book". Instead, you should have a fk from the book to the book store. This is saying "a book belongs to a bookstore (and only one bookstore)"

```
class Book:
    bookstore = models.ForeignKey("Bookstore")

class Bookstore:
    ...
```

You need to use an [inline form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) if you want to add multiple books while editing your bookstore object:

```
class BookInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Book

class BookstoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    model = Bookstore
    inlines = [BookInline,]
```

Comment: No you said "a model bookstore which has a foreign key to book model". At the moment your `Book` model has a foreign key to a `Bookstore`. Your code and text are contradicting each other.

Comment: thanks :) . One more thing, and what if i want a circular relation? wherein bookstore also has a foreign key to books ? is that the correct way? to just add a foreignkey field?

Comment: Django provides reverse relationships automatically. You can do `bookstore.books_set.all()` to get all the books in a bookstore. You can also name it something more sensible using related_name field in the ForeignKey definition, so if you do `bookstore = ForeignKey(BookStore, related_name='books')` you can refer to books as `bookstore.books.all()`

Comment: That said, the way you have things right now, each book can only be sold in one store. You might consider using ManyToMany field, so the same book can be sold in many book stores and each book store can sell many different books.